# Returning Keys from nested dictionaries excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, nested

I have problem that the keys of the nested dictionaries are returning to the calling sub function. It returns the Run time error '424' Object Required

```
Set LoadCombinationDict = LCaseDict()
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(file_name, True)

    For Each LCKey In LoadCombinationDict.Keys
        Line = LCKey
        For Each AddnlKey In AddnlCaseDict.Keys
            X = LoadCombinationDict(LCKey)(AddnlKey)
            Line = Line & ";" & X
        Next AddnlKey
        a.WriteLine (Line)
     Next LCKey
a.Close
```

Below is the function which create a nested dictionary

```
Function LCaseDict() as Scripting.Dictionary
'Some Code to create nested dictionary
End Function
```

The dictionary works perfect if I include the above code in the sub function. Is there a way to return keys of both the main and nested dictionaries to the calling function in excel vba?

Comment: You're properly returning the dictionary correct? What line does your error occur on?

Comment: Please show your code for LCaseDict and LoadCombinationDict. What is x? On what line does the error occour?

Comment: The error was in the line X = LoadCombinationDict(LCKey)(AddnlKey). Thanks to suggestions from Thomas, it worked well. Additionally, I reset the variable "Line" after each LCKey loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to iterate over a Dictionary of Dictionaries

```
Set LoadCombinationDict = LCaseDict()
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(file_name, True)

    For Each LCKey In LoadCombinationDict.Keys
        For Each AddnlKey In LoadCombinationDict(LCKey).Keys
            X = LoadCombinationDict(LCKey)(AddnlKey)
            Line = Line & ";" & X
        Next AddnlKey
        a.WriteLine (Line)
     Next LCKey
a.Close
```